# Variable returning undefined right before it gets populated with data from api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, asynchronous, promise

Hey so I have a small web **scraper** in my backend using express.js

```
const scrapeMetatags = (text) => {

  const urls = Array.from( getUrls(text) );

  const requests = urls.map(async url => {

      const res = await fetch(url);

      const html = await res.text();
      const $ = cheerio.load(html);
      const getMetatag = (name) =>  
          $(`meta[name=${name}]`).attr('content') ||  
          $(`meta[name="og:${name}"]`).attr('content') ||  
          $(`meta[name="twitter:${name}"]`).attr('content');

      return { 
          url,
          title: $('title').first().text(),
          favicon: $('link[rel="shortcut icon"]').attr('href'),
          // description: $('meta[name=description]').attr('content'),
          description: getMetatag('description'),
          image: getMetatag('image'),
          author: getMetatag('author'),
      }
  });
  return Promise.all(requests);
}

app.get("/scraper/:link", async (req, res) => {
  const {link} = req.params;
  const body = link
  const data = await scrapeMetatags(body)
  res.json(data)
})
```

Then in my frontend/react I'm calling it like so:

```
const [websitedescription, setwebsitedescription] = useState(null)
useEffect(() => {
        async function scraper() {
            const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/scraper/${scraperlink}`)
            const data = await response.json()
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
            const websitedescription = data[0].description
            console.log(websitedescription) 
            const logolink = data[0].favicon
            setwebsitedescription(websitedescription)
        }
        scraper()
    }, [scraperlink])
```

The issue that I'm running into is that I'm getting a

**Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'description')
at scraper**

right before the data gets populated. Which I believe might be because my component renders before the API has time to populate the data. I can confirm that the data actually gets called by looking in the console. I've put the returned object in stringified form so you can that what mean.

[image]

As you can see the error occurs right before the data is returned/populated. What can I do to fix this? thnks in advance

Comment: Can I see where you are rendering ```websitedescription```? Also keep in mind variables used for useState() should always be camel case.

Comment: @yangcodes **websitedescription** is currently being rendered in its current component in the return statement like so **<p>{websitedescription}</p>**. This component is being rendered in another parent component